# Найти элемент по содержимому

Tags: php, парсер

Имеем список:

```
<ul>
    <li>Состав: медь, свинец</li>
    <li>Длина: 1м</li>
    <li>Вес: 5кг</li>
    <li>Страна: Россия</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно из всего списка получить содержимое li в котором есть слово "состав". Как возможно решить данную задачу?

Comment: Вы хотите перехватить на этапе формирования страницы или по факту уже в готовой странице? Если в готовой то php серверный язык, вы должны вначале получить данные страницы и только потом обрабатывать данные.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov парсер. Находит на странице донора необходимые данные, а из них уже нужно выделить строку, которая содержит слово "состав". Все было бы проще, если бы порядок строк соблюдался. Но стоки могут стоять в любой очередности, соответственно "состав" может находится как в начале, так и конце, или середине списка.

Comment: Спасибо. Я знаю что такое парсер :) Я просто уточнил.

Comment: ) понимаю что знаете) Просто был уточняющий вопрос, постарался подробнее описать суть работы. Типовые задачи решать получается, а вот более сложные еще не поддаются..

Comment: откуда у вас берётся этот список?

Comment: @mymedia как говорил выше в комментарии - списки тащит php парсер (DiDOM, если быть совсем точным), и эти данные нужно разложить так сказать по полочкам, вычленив нужную информацию из конкретной строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php есть готовый набор классов для работы с html-документом - та самая [объектная модель документа, DOM](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php). Просто загрузите документ и сможете делать по нему xpath-запросы на поиск нужных нод:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<ul>
    <li>foo: 123</li>
    <li>bar: 456</li>
    <li>baz: 789</li>
</ul>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query("//ul//li[contains(text(), 'foo')]");

echo "found: '{$entries[0]->nodeValue}'";
```

Выводит:

```
found: 'foo: 123'
```

Про xpath можно почитать хотябы в вики, [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Comment: спасибо, ваш вариант с xPath удалось использовать. Его то я как раз и упустил из виду

Comment: А как вывести только текст из этой строки, без обертки li, не подскажите?

Comment: @Amsterdam не понял про обёртку. вроде мой пример только текст и выводит

Comment: и вариант с выводом через nodeValue сложно использовать в иных контекстах. По крайней мере, у меня основной код не подхватывает из него информацию

Comment: в добавок, почему то не находит кириллические значения

Comment: @Amsterdam просто укажите кодировку `new DOMDocument('UTF-8');` и загружайте документ как xml, а не html `->loadXML(..`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, если вы получаете лишки из базы или прочего, и выводите их:

```
$data = [
    'Состав' => 'медь, свинец',
    'Длина' => '1м',
    'Вес' => '5кг',
    'Страна' => 'Россия',
    ];

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if ($key==="Состав") echo "<li><strong>{$key}: {$value}</strong></li>";
    else echo "<li>{$key}: {$value}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```